# Infinitely moving tunnels are not aligning correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If you can imagine a game where the player is traveling through a tunnel forever. To do this, my camera is stationary and the tunnel moves backwards to give the illusion of movement.

There is always 3 mini tunnels on screen at once stuck together and when one moves out of the players view, a new one is generated at the front to give the illusion that its infinite.

This is working fine except when a piece of tunnel gets deleted. The tunnel after that seems to stop moving for one frame which causes the one in front of that to move inside it and overlap and I'm not sure why.

Each tunnel is exactly 116.25 in length and the first tunnel is on screen by default.

```
//An array to store the pre made tunnels for easy difficulty
public GameObject[] easyTunnels;

//List of tunnels that are currently on screen
public List<GameObject> tunnels = new List<GameObject>();

float speed = 0.5f;
int level = 0;

//A list of all of the tunnels for every difficulty(only easy atm)
List<GameObject[]> levelsArray = new List<GameObject[]>();

void Start () 
{
    levelsArray.Add(easyTunnels);

    //Spawn 2 tunnels for a total of 3 in a row. Starting tunnel already exists
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int randomTunnel = Random.Range(0, easyTunnels.Length);
        Vector3 startingPos = new Vector3(0, 0, 116.25f * i);
        GameObject tunnel = Instantiate(easyTunnels[randomTunnel]);
        tunnel.transform.position = startingPos;
        tunnels.Add(tunnel);
    }
}

void Update () 
{
    //For each tunnel on the map
    for (int i = 0; i < tunnels.Count; i++)
    {
        //As its moving on the z axis, get that value
        Transform tunnelPos = tunnels[i].transform;
        float zPos = tunnelPos.position.z;

        //Each tunnel is exactly 116.25 in length
        //If it reaches this, it means its off screen as the tunnel starts at 0
        if (zPos < -116.25f)
        {
            //Get the spawn point of the new tunnel. The existing position + the length of 3 tunnels
            float newZPos = zPos + 348.75f;

            //Destroy this one as we dont need it anymore
            Destroy(tunnels[i]);
            tunnels.RemoveAt(i);

            //And spawn the new one
            int randomTunnel = Random.Range(0, easyTunnels.Length);
            Vector3 startingPos = new Vector3(0, 0, newZPos);
            GameObject tunnel = Instantiate(levelsArray[level][randomTunnel]);
            tunnel.transform.position = startingPos;
            tunnels.Add(tunnel);

        }

        //If the tunnel exists, then move it
        if (tunnels[i] != null)
        {
            tunnelPos.position = new Vector3(tunnelPos.position.x, tunnelPos.position.y, zPos -= speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Why it's doing this?

Comment: When you remove a tunnel from the list ('tunnels.RemoveAt(i);') you probably need to drop the counter of i by one, because imagine it like this: tunnel[0] get removed (i =0) you generate one new tunnel and add it to the screen (which will be tunnel[3]) now on the next loop, it will be i=1; but it will be pointing to the tunnel[2] becasue you removed one, so you skipped one.
Try it and see what happens. for a fast check try commenting ` tunnels.Add(tunnel); which is inside the loop and see if you are getting and IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: ah this makes sense, i didnt realise lists would automaticly adjust its index's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting and instantiating the game object might be relatively expensive to do in a single frame, but i can't say much about that not knowing anything about their geometry, materials, etc.

What i can tell however, is that your way of removing and adding tunnels possibly causes one tunnel not to be updated for every frame, and another one updated *twice* instead.

you are doing the following :

```
for index i =0, do while i < the number of tunnels
  if the tunnel is too far away
    destroy it and create a new one, add it to the end of the list of tunnels
    reposition the tunnel at index i
```

If you are handling the second tunnel, and it's too far away, it gets removed and a new tunnel is added to the end of the list.
It's repositioned, and then we go to the next item in the list (which is the tunnel you just added and repositioned already)

maybe try replacing the item at the current index with the new tunnel so you don't mess up the order in which your tunnels are updated while iterating over them. Make sure you are using `List<T>` for your `tunnels` variable, and try this :

```
        //do not call tunnels.RemoveAt(i); instead : 

        //And spawn the new one
        int randomTunnel = Random.Range(0, easyTunnels.Length);
        Vector3 startingPos = new Vector3(0, 0, newZPos);
        GameObject tunnel = Instantiate(levelsArray[level][randomTunnel]);
        tunnel.transform.position = startingPos;
        tunnels[i] = tunnel;
```

bonus tip : also, it just moves them by a specific amount for every frame rendered.

Since the amount of frames rendered per second is variable, the speed of your tunnel sections might dip or jump along with the framerate.

try the following :

```
tunnelPos.position = new Vector3(tunnelPos.position.x, tunnelPos.position.y, zPos -= speed * Time.DeltaTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the info, I have since adopted TheSkimek's method but I can see you put alot of effort in answering. I will use your delta time way for moving though

Comment: @RachelDockter TheSkimek's answer makes things more readable and keeps it easy to understand (i upvoted it because it was a good idea), so that's good! I put in the effort for that long answer because half the battle in programming is in understanding what is happening and why ;) and insight is a valuable thing. happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Deleting and Adding from an array while looping through it at the same time is never a good idea.

I would suggest another approach:

1. Create a TunnelManager Empty with a script attached to it that just spawns a random piece of the tunnel prefab array.
2. Give every tunnel prefab a script which a) Moves it down and b) Deletes itself when it reaches the endpoint (that 116.25f). Before doing that it should call the "Spawn new tunnel piece" method of the TunnelManager Empty.

Like this there is no need of looping through the Array every frame and adding or deleting from it.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the original problem but this sounds like a better idea, i will try this